# iPhone provisioning profile renewal help

Tags: iphone, profile, provisioning

my problem is that my provisiong profile expired a few days ago.  I visited the developer's portal and downloaded a new one (made it the same name and everything).

I followed the instructions and installed the new one and removed the old.  I can now run my app on my iPhone again :) but whenever i try to test my app on my iPhone from Xcode i get the error: provisioning profile expired.

When i check in the 'Organizer' the new profile doesn't expire til 22 May and on the iPhone the profile is verified and again doesn't expire til 22 May.

Did i forget to remove something from somewhere and Xcode is still seeing the old profile?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change the provisioning profile to the new one in your build configuration? Even if it has the same name you have to select the new one. Don't foret to clean all targets ;)

Comment: Its ok, sorted it.  It was a combination of not setting the new profile (found in the code signing section) and I also had to delete the old expired profile from the iPhone, as both the new and old were still on there (achieved by using the iPhone configuration utility).  Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Shingoo and simo311, you saved me from asking the same question.